# Totalling based on expression field

Tags: reporting-services

In reporting services, I have used

```
=IIf(Fields!Weekday.Value="Su"
        or Fields!Weekday.Value="Sa"
        or Len(Fields!HOLIDAY.Value)>0,
      (Fields!GENERAL.Value 
       + Fields!LAUNCH.Value
       + Fields!SHIFT.Value
       + Fields!OCESAWE.Value
       + Fields!OCESAWD.Value
       + Fields!WEPHWORK.Value
       + Fields!OCREMWE.Value
       + Fields!OCREMWD.Value) * 1.5,
     (Fields!GENERAL.Value
       + Fields!LAUNCH.Value
       + Fields!SHIFT.Value
       + Fields!OCESAWE.Value
       + Fields!OCESAWD.Value
       + Fields!WEPHWORK.Value
       + Fields!OCREMWE.Value
       + Fields!OCREMWD.Value)
   )
```

To get a columnn called "Total Weighted" and this column have several rows.

```
 1. ID         Total Weighted 

 2. 111          21
 3. 121          49
```

How can I get the total of the "Total Weighted?

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated field in your dataset, and use the formula you provided as the value of that field. Now you can refer to that field elsewhere as if it came from your database.

So then you'd use an expression like `=SUM(Fields!TotalWeighted.Value)` in your tablix.

Comment: Thanks Jamie.  I tried this and it gave me error: "The expression used for the calculated field '=SUM(Fields!TotalWeighted.Value)' includes an aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous or lookup function. Aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous and lookup functions cannot be used in calculated field expressions.

Comment: The calculated field shouldn't contain the aggregate. It should only contain your original formula from your question. This will give you the conditional value for each row of your dataset. Then use the aggregate expression (`=SUM(...)`) in your tablix or where you need to display the total.